# Form redirection after validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, redirect

So I'm making an excercise in class (don't find the logic in it, but it's alright).
All validations like patterns, required, all rules and messages are done with jQuery validate and it runs perfect. 
The problem is:
I have a login form, when user is not registered I redirect the user to a complete registration form, the thing is that I don't know how to redirect the user to `"gallery.html"` after registering and validating and checking that all fields are filled.
Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
  <form name="formulario_registro" id="formulario_registro" action="" method="POST">

        <label for="nif">NIF</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="nif" id="nif" placeholder="&#127380;" readonly>
        <br>

        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="colortexto" id="nombre" placeholder="&#128100;" readonly>

        <br>

        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="colortexto" id="apellidos" placeholder="&#128100;" readonly>

        <br>

        <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label> <br>
        <input type="number" name="telefono" class="colortexto" id="telefono" placeholder="&#128222;" min="600000000">

        <br>

        <label for="direccion">Dirección</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="direccion" class="colortexto" id="direccion" placeholder="&#127968; ">

        <br>

        <label for="email">Email</label> <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="colortexto" id="email" placeholder="&#64; ">

        <br>


    <button type="submit" id="enviar">Enviar</button>


</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //This is to fill the inputs from the login form in the current registration form. Not important, this works fine.
        $("#nif").val(localStorage.getItem("nif"));
        $("#nombre").val(localStorage.getItem("nombre"));
        $("#apellidos").val(localStorage.getItem("apellidos"));

        //this is the submit button, enviar is "send".

        $('#enviar').click(function(){

            alert("User has been registered succesfully, will be redirected to the gallery.");
            window.open("galeria.html");

        });

    });
```

EDIT: Someone asked to see my validations, they're in another different .js that is linked in the head of the HTML as well as the css, .js, libraries and so on. As I said, they run perfect, the redirecting is the only problem that I didn't know how to solve :)
Thank you so much for helping me!!!

Here they are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z][a-z\s]*$/i.test(value);
    }, "Sólo letras y espacios");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("nifcorrecto", function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE]$/i.test(value);
}, "NIF incorrecto");    



$("#formulario_registro").validate({

    rules:{

        nif:{
            required:true,
            nifcorrecto:true
        },

        nombre:{
            required:true,
            rangelength:[3, 20],
            lettersonly:true
        },

        apellidos:{
            required:true,
            rangelength: [3,50],
            lettersonly:true
        },

        telefono:{
            required:true,
            min:600000000,
            max: 799999999
        },

        direccion:{
            required:true,
            minlength:4,
            maxlength:255
        },

        email:{
            required:true,
            email:true
        },
    },

    messages:{

        nif:{
            required:"Este campo es obligatorio",
            nifcorrecto:"Formato de DNI incorrecto"
        },

        nombre:{
            required:"Por favor, introduzca un nombre",
            rangelength:"El número de caracteres mínimo es de 3 hasta un máximo de 20",
        },

        apellidos:{
            required: "Por favor introduzca los apellidos",
            rangelength:"El número de caracteres mínimo es de 3 hasta un máximo de 50"
        },
        telefono:{
            required: "Introduzca su número de teléfono", 
            min: "Número de teléfono móvil debe ser entre 600000000 y 799999999",
            max: "Número de teléfono móvil debe ser entre 600000000 y 799999999"
        },

        direccion:{
            required:"Debe inrtoducir una dirección",
            minlength:"La dirección debe tener al menos 4 caracteres",
            maxlength:"La dirección debe tener como máximo 255 caracteres"
        },

        email:{
            required:"Es necesario introducir un email de contacto",
            email:"El formato de email no es correcto"
        },

    }
});


});
```

So, I know this is wrong, if I click, it doesn't matter if the fields are empty, it just redirect to `galeria.html` (gallery) and do not listen to the validation.
I have (in another different .js).
 So I need to click, check if the fields are filled with the correct validated data and then redirect to `galeria.html`.
 I don't know how to do this, please help! 
If I delete all the `" $('#enviar').click(function()....... "` It validates the fields and warn me they're wrong or empy, but obviously doesn't redirect me anywhere.

PS: Spanish is not a problem, it works perfectly.

Comment: Where you have put the validations.., kindly show that code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a `boolean` variable that becomes `false` if the data is not valid like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //This is to fill the inputs from the login form in the current registration form. Not important, this works fine.
    $("#nif").val(localStorage.getItem("nif"));
    $("#nombre").val(localStorage.getItem("nombre"));
    $("#apellidos").val(localStorage.getItem("apellidos"));

    //this is the submit button, enviar is "send".

    $('#enviar').click(function(){
        var valid = true;
        // your validations
        if($("#nif").val() == ""){
           valid = false;
        }
        // and so on all your validations
        if(valid){ // only if no errors
           alert("User has been registered succesfully, will be redirected to the gallery.");
           window.open("galeria.html");
        }

    });
});
```

If you want to redirect instead of opening a new window you can use:
`location.replace("galeria.html");`

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much! I'm going to try this right now. :)